# Problema com conexão de SQL Server à partir do PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Eu estava usando um programa em **PHP** que conectava e lia um banco de dados SQL Server. Do nada ele parou de funcionar apresentando a seguinte mensagem :

**O cliente não pode estabelecer conexão porque foi encontrado um erro durante os handshakes anteriores ao logon. As causas comuns incluem a tentativa do cliente de conectar-se a uma versão sem suporte do SQL Server, o servidor muito ocupado para aceitar novas conexões ou uma limitação de recursos (memória ou máximo de conexões permitidas) no servidor.**

Algumas informações para esclarecer :

1-Consigo conectar o banco via Dbeaver da própria máquina que o programa PHP deixou de funcionar

2-De outra máquina consigo  conectar esse mesmo banco com o mesmo programa PHP

3-Essa mesma máquina conecta outro banco SQL Server de outro cliente

Ou seja, o mesmo programa conecta o mesmo banco mas de outra máquina e a mesma máquina consegue conectar outro banco SQL.

O que pode ser?

Comment: Inicialmente seria verificar se estão todos com a versão atualizada...

Comment: Em princípio está tudo atualizado tanto é que da mesma máquina acesso outro banco e o banco consegue ser acessado por outra máquina. Acrescento que acesso esse banco via VPN